# Python cffi is isolated by windows defender

Tags: python, windows, cffi

When I install paramiko on pycharm

```
pip install paramiko
```

I got message
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12KPv.png)

At the same time, I received the windows defender message and determined _cffi_backend.cp36-win_amd64.pyd as a Trojan(Win32/Skeeyah.I).

Is this a misjudgment?
Can I just stop windows defender to install it? 
Is this safe?

Answer (score 0):

`paramiko` has dependency `pycrypto`

You follow those solutions :

```
pip install pycrypto
pip install paramiko
```

If face more problem comment below

Comment: My problem is I want to use paramiko. 
When I want to install paramiko on pycharm
Windows defender isolation cffi_backend and then can not be installed it.(Windows defender judges cffi_backend is a Trojan(Win32/Skeeyah.I))

Can I just stop windows defender to install it?
Is this safe?

Comment: I try to install pycrypto but show:  
Command "c:...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SHUNLI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1013wz1g\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(c
ompile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:...\pip-record-vk4bcd06\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\SHUNLI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1013wz1g\pycrypto\

Comment: try to install from here http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto

Comment: Finally, after I tried to reinstall Python, everything worked fine. Thank you for your help.